# How to download derby database download for netbeans web app

Tags: database, netbeans, jar, derby

[image]

Probably a stupid question but I want to download a derby database to use in my netbeans web app. I have a windows 64 bit. Do I have to download all those distributions?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to download them all.

The 'bin distribution' should be fine for you.

If this is your first time working with Derby, may I suggest that you spend a few hours going through the tutorials: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/getstart/